# VMware vSphere as gateway to internal network

Tags: routing, vmware-vsphere, subnet

I'm looking for info if it's possible for vSphere to act as gateway from my external network to an internal network.
Basically: The vSphere host is on a 10.0.0.0/24 which is my "external" network. This one is pretty limited in terms of IPs I can get. I wanted to put all the VMs on e.g. a 192.168.0.0/24. But they would need to communicate with the hosts on the 10.0.0.0/24 too.

I know this sounds easy if you just route that on the respective gateway, but that is kinda out question for my scenario due to internal reasons.

So, can I setup the vSphere host to route packets for the 192.168.0.0/24 to my VMs? Of course with setting up a static route on the hosts that have to reach this net. Or do I need to put up a "router" VM with access to both subnets to handle the routing for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MichelZ got it right.

To expand on this though; ask your network people to create a new non-routed VLAN for you which is internal to the switch your hosts are on.  Then it doesn't matter how many external IPs you have and your host and their VMs can reach each other if you set it up correctly.  This eliminates the need and complexity of a "router VM" which is just asking for trouble.

Comment: +1 and will accept this for providing an alternative solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm reasonably sure this is an incorrect answer sorry, that or you've not explaining it clearly enough - one way or another this needs routing somewhere.

Comment: Did this really work? I don't understand how it could... even with a few dirty hacks that I can think of: If your hosts in 10.0.0.0/24 receive IP packets from your VMs in 192.168.0.0/24, they would send their answers to their gateway. Which doesn't know what to do with 192.168.0.0/24 IPs and forwards them to its default gateway, not to the VMs. I agree with MichelZ that you need a routing instance and, if your networking guys won't give you one, can build one yourself with a VM. You could do NATing and firewalling on this VM, too ;-)

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't do that on the host directly. You need a VM to handle the routing. ESX is not a router.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. Now I can go bug my network people ;)